# onClick() Method can not find Exception

Tags: java, android

I get this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Clicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button2'

I'm using in my app a different java class.

My Java Class

```
https://pasteb  in.com/gwdf1Zrf
```

My XML

```
https://pasteb  in.com/b0SQUPvW
```

I can get `onClick()` method on `MainActivity` but I want to get on " `another.java` "

Comment: Please post your code here, not in external links.

Answer (score 0):

in your xml, start typing the onClick attribute until your method shows up

```
android:onClick="Clicked" //while typing, the methods in your activity will show up here if they are public
```

if it does not show up make sure your xml is actually set for your activity.
in the top of your xml

```
 tools:context
```

and your function set to public